# Store a PDF file in my MongoDB database with PYmongo error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I want to store a PDF file in my MongoDB database (In Ubuntu) with with PYMonbgo and gridfs.
But I am receiving the error ***'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte***

How can I store and receive a PDF with python in MongoDB?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs

db = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/').myDB
fs = gridfs.GridFS( db )
fileID = fs.put( open(('Test.pdf')  ))
out = fs.get(fileID)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the PDF appropriately after reading. I won't pretend to understand the details. But I have gotten it to work. Try this, see if it works for you too.
(FYI, Might want to also specify the collection)

```
import base64
import gridfs

def write_new_pdf(path):
    db = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/').myDB
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    # Note, open with the "rb" flag for "read bytes"
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    with fs.new_file(
        chunkSize=800000,
        filename=path) as fp:
        fp.write(encoded_string)
```

**Updaate: How to read the pdf back**

```
def read_pdf(filename):
    # Usual setup
    db = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/').myDB
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    # Standard query to Mongo
    data = fs.find_one(filter=dict(filename=filename))
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(data.read()))
```

Comment: Do you know how I can receive this "Test.pdf" back from my "myDB" collection by just passing the file name "Test.pdf" to a function?

Comment: I think that will work. Shout if it doesn't. A little busy atm but can look later.

Comment: What do I do If I need to extract text from the PDF extracted and not save it in my PC?